# sharing window of twitter close automatically

Tags: javascript, twitter

share window of a twitter close automatically.i want to stay window until user close this window?

```
function()
{   
  link=https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=WATCH;
  window.open(link, 'window', 'width=700, height=500');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3hxm0gr4/1/  works for me

Comment: Popup blocker of your browser interfering?

Comment: no marvin..my pop up is open and and it is go to twitter after the tweet the window close automatically

Comment: Gustav i have already  used on click  function.return false is not working